# django custom 404 not working..context variable not showing

Tags: python, django

I use django 1.6

In myapp1/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url, handler404  

# url patterns... 
#  
#  

handler404 = 'myapp1.views.custom_page_not_found'
```

myapp1/views.py

```
def custom_page_not_found(request):

    ## 404 custom code start ##
    ### some query set here
    context ={}
    context['var1']=qs1

    resp = render_to_response('404.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    resp.status_code = 404
    return resp

    ## 404 custom code end ##
```

myapp1/templates/404.html

```
<!-- html code bla bla bla -->

<ul>
{% for x in var1 %}
<li>{{x.name}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I have tested the code using dummy/test view in debug/development and it's working.
But when I put the code inside `custom_page_not_found`, the rendered 404 page in live server is empty between the `<ul></ul>`

Help?

EDIT:
After further investigation seems my custom view is not invoked. Django still uses its own default 404 view. Still don't know the solution :(

Comment: Actually in debug mode it should not be working at all. How was that you first had an empty `<ul>` and then the default Django view?

Comment: Yeah in debug mode it's not working. I have to use dummy view. That's why I said in 'live server'. The reason why I know django still use its own view is, I put a log inside custom_page_not_found and I don't see it in the log. Seems that django still render 404.html but because it's rendered by django default view,my context variable is none,hence empty <ul>.